# Asp with including files error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I cant find normal manual about asp including files
So i have site root folder `D:\site\Root\`
When i have file index.asp `d:\site\Root\index.asp`

when i have header.inc `d:\site\include\header.inc`

1. How to include header.inc into index.asp without enabling AspEnableParentPaths ?
2. So what is difference between

> ```
> <!-- #Include virtual=
> <!-- #Include file=
> ```

What is virtual path?

3. If i have

> index.asp
>
> `<!--#include file="include/function.inc"-->`
>
> `<!--#include file="include/header.inc"-->`
>
> header.inc
>
> `<!--#include file="include/bottom.inc"-->`
>
> bottom.inc
>
> `<%=transl("Login")%>`

So function `<%=transl("Login")%>` in `bottom.inc` is not working with error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch: 'transl',

until i  include  `<!--#include file="include/function.inc"-->` inside `bottom.inc` 
But i need use `function.inc` in all files included from index.asp! So i need to include `function.inc` in each file included in `index.asp` ?

Comment: Why did you tag this as `asp.net` and `asp-classic` despite the fact that they're completely separate technologies?

Comment: Because i start learning asp today

Comment: Now you've removed the `asp-classic` tag and left the `asp.net` tag, despite the fact that your question is clearly about `asp-classic`. By the way, why are you learning `asp-classic`? It's pretty much a dead technology and new projects should not be implemented with it. You should switch to learning ASP.NET Web Forms (and use master pages) or ASP.NET MVC (and use layouts)

Comment: Can you give a link to best tutorial Asp.net MVC?

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/include-virtual-or-include-file.2778836/

Comment: Assuming that your directory "Root" is your root directory you will need to make "Includes" a subdirectory of "Root", either by physically moving it or my making it a virtual directory through IIS Manager if you don't want to enable parent paths